# Regex for specific format

Tags: c#, regex

I'm a newbie at using regex in c# and I'm trying to use it to validate a phone number with this format 09oxoxxxxxx where x can be any number and o can be only 1-9 and the total length should be 11 numbers. Here's what I think which is probably wrong.

```
if (Regex.IsMatch("09203041152", "^[0]{1}[9]{1}[1-9]{2}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{6}"))
```

Comment: *shouldn't be 11* or *should be 11*?

Comment: Sorry was a typo, fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following RegExp should match the format you stated '09oxoxxxxxx'

```
^09[1-9][0-9][1-9][0-9]{6}$
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use shorthand character `\d` which represents any number `[0-9]`:

```
Regex.IsMatch("09203041152", @"^09[1-9]\d[1-9]\d{6}$")
```

Your patter is not working due to repetitions count `{2}` here:

> > `^[0]{1}[9]{1}`**[1-9]{2}**`[1-9]{1}[0-9]{6}`

That requires two non-zero numbers in a row. But you need one non-zero number and one any number at this place:

> > `^[0]{1}[9]{1}`**[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}**`[1-9]{1}[0-9]{6}`

Note - you don't need to specify repetitions count equal to `{1}`, because that means single token occurrence, which is true without specifying that explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why it is not working. for some reason your post wasn't here when I checked answers :\ up voted

Comment: @arashmoeen possibly you didn't refresh browser :)

Comment: If I had added some answer, I would have never tried to explain how the OP's code was wrong, +1 for that :) sometimes the best answer is not the accepted answer.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Oh I sure did, because I didn't left the page open. that's strange. thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is a bit more complex that it needs to be:

```
^09[1-9][0-9][1-9][0-9]{6}$
```

- `^`: Match the start-of-line.
- `09`: Matches the number `0` followed by `0`.
- `[1-9]`: Matches any number between `1` and `9`.
- `[0-9]`: Matches any number between `0` and `9`.
- `[1-9]`: Again matches any number between `1` and `9`.
- `[0-9]{6}`: Matches any number between `0` and `9` six times.
- Now the total number of digits matched is `11`.

Comment: sorry Udi was faster, but I up voted you for explaining the structure, cleared many things for me. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @arashmoeen Yes he was. Don't worry about it, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^09[1-9][0-9][1-9][0-9]{6}
```